# Difference between list.map and list.collect

Tags: collections, f#

What is the difference between map and collect? documentation below - i cant tell the difference..

---

List.map<'T,'U> Function

Creates a new collection whose elements are the results of applying the given function to each of the elements of the collection.

// Signature:
List.map : ('T -> 'U) -> 'T list -> 'U list

---

List.collect<'T,'U> Function

For each element of the list, applies the given function. Concatenates all the results and returns the combined list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The difference is that the output list from `map` is the same length as the input list.  For `collect`, the output list may be longer or shorter than the input as the function you pass returns a list instead of a single element.

For more detail - compare the signatures.  For `map`

```
List.map : ('T -> 'U) -> 'T list -> 'U list
```

and collect

```
List.collect : ('T -> 'U list) -> 'T list -> 'U list
```

you can see here that the return type of the function argument is different.

Comment: `List.collect` is also known as `flatMap` (in other languages). Ref [F# Friday – The collect Function](https://bradcollins.com/2015/05/01/f-friday-the-collect-function/)

Answer (score 15):

**An example for illustration**

Let's say you have a list of lists:

`let list = [ [1; 2]; [3; 4]; [5; 6] ]`

And a transformation function:

`let trans = fun x -> [for i in x -> i*10]`

---

`List.map trans list` will produce:

`[[10; 20]; [30; 40]; [50; 60]]`

While

`List.collect trans list` will produce:

`[10; 20; 30; 40; 50; 60]`

---

`List.collect` will apply the transformation function and will `Concatenate` the result while `List.map` will only apply the transformation function.

Answer (score 11):

Adding to @John's answer, the difference is in the word `Concatenates`.

Basically, `List.collect f xs` is the same as `List.concat (List.map f xs)`.